# Why sometimes it is correct not to put a comma after an if-clause?

Tags: conditional-constructions, punctuation, commas

There is a recommendation to put a comma after an if-clause which is placed at the beginning of a sentence. For example:

> If there was the time when songs like this were not needed**,** I would not live to see it.

But here is the sentence:

> If you had married this girl you would have been wretched.

Why does it go with no comma?

Answer (score 5):

In that case I would say the comma is just there for clarity. You can easily interpret a simple, short sentence, but a longer one with no commas would be harder to comprehend.

Comment: To be a little more explicit: a recommendation is *only* a recommendation.  It's a useful thing to consider, but following it won't always be necessary or even a good idea.